# Format dateTimePicker like yyyy-yyyy (2020/2021) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project for college and it's Yearbook project. I need to put years in exact format yyyy/yyyy (eg. 2020/2021) can anyone help me to parse and make a validation?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you share your code?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in a `DateTimePicker` in the first place? Just have a dropdown with a list of years?

Comment: @DavidG thanks for this idea <3 ^_^ :)

Answer (score 3):

I know that you have probably found an answer already, the code is for anyone in the future that may have the same issue.

You won't make use of a date picker, but rather a list of dropdowns showing the different sessions.

Check the code below

```
        //subtract the current year from two years to start from the previous year
        var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 2; 
        List<string> allsessions = new List<string>();

        //loop for the next five years
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            //add curent year by one to get the next year
            var nextYear = currentYear + 1;
            var label = $"{currentYear}/{nextYear}";

            //add data to list
            allsessions.Add(label);
            currentYear = nextYear;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All Sessions: \n"+string.Join(", ", allsessions));

        Console.ReadLine();

        // output will be:
        // All Sessions:
        // 2021/2022, 2022/2023, 2023/2024, 2024/2025, 2025/2026
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool CheckDateYear(string s)
        {
            string s1 = s.Split('/')[0];//s.Split('-')[0]
            string s2 = s.Split('/')[1];
            if (DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() != s2 || (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString() != s1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

...

       if(CheckDateYear("2020/2021")
       {
          ...
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use regex to validate:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] values= { "2020/2021", "2019-2020", 
                              "199e-2000" };
      Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}(/\d{4})"); // 4 digits, forward slash, 4 digits
      foreach (string value in values)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a valid entry.", 
                           value, 
                           rgx.IsMatch(value) ? "is" : "is not");
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//      2020/2021 is a valid entry.
//      2019-2020 is not a valid entry.
//      199e-2000 is not a valid entry.
```